# TextView overlapping on another in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am working in design part of my project.

I have the layout as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textviewIdPushDate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageviewIdPushPopup" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewIdPushShowName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Show" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewIdPushEmailId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Show" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewIdPushAlert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Show" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewIdPushDate"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Show" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageviewIdPushPopup"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this layout, the `RelativeLayout` which contains 3 `TextViews` not ordered one by one as expected in 10 `inch` `Samsung` tablet. The same working fine in 7 `inch` tablet.

I had put my effort up to my level. Could anyone figure out the mistake I did, if any?

And suggest some designing tutorials for `Android`.

Comment: In different screens of device it will obtain different pixels and space. So in big screen it will be disordered. You can either use linearlayout with weight property or use property of relativelayout properly.

Comment: increase the height of relative layout, as the ppi is more of 10 inch tablet the 80 dp becomes to small.Use two layouts for 7 inch and 10 inch.

Comment: What i can under stand from question, you want to show three text views aligned horizontally in 10 inch tablet and vertically in other devices, Is it so.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout, so you will have the 3 textViews well ordered, vertically or horizontally, like this (in the code i put the vertical orientation)

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textviewIdPushDate"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageviewIdPushPopup"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewIdPushShowName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Show" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewIdPushEmailId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Show" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewIdPushAlert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Show" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

and for Android Design tutorials, i think the best thing to do in the first place is to use the official tutorials :
http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Hope that may help.